# Insertion of image in mysql using jsp HTTP Status 404 not found

Tags: mysql, jsp

I get some error as 404 not found error plz help me. Insertion of image in mysql using jsp HTTP Status 404 not found.i m trying to insert image in mysql database and i have used mysql jdbc driver.

**In index.jsp**

```
                    <%-- 
                        Document   : index
                        Created on : 23-Jan-2017, 11:51:34
                        Author     : AshwinKArki
                    --%>

                    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                            <title>JSP Page</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                             <form name="f1" method="post" action="main">
                                Select file:<input type="file" name="file1" >
                                <input type="submit" value="insert" />
                            </form>
                        </body>
                    </html>
```

**in Main.jsp** : another page

```
                    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
                    <%@page import="java.io.*" %>
                    <%
                        String file2=request.getParameter("file1");
                        try{
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/storefile");
                            String sql="INSERT INTO tbl_image VALUES (?)";
                            PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                            stmt.setString(1,file2);
                            stmt.executeUpdate();
                            out.print("Suucesfull");
                            stmt.close();
                            conn.close();

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            out.print(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        %>

*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not forwarding to the right action , since your action is a jsp file so you should set the extension too , not like servlet when you set just the name of the file , so there must be : `action="main.jsp"` and not `action="main"`

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="main.jsp">
    Select file:<input type="file" name="file1" >
    <input type="submit" value="insert" />
</form>
```

Comment: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'storefile' it says such error after i put main.jsp

Comment: it means that you're setting a password to access to your database and you have to specify it on `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/storefile",username,password);` if it's not let it blank